# Conditional - Try something for x seconds

Tags: python, web-scraping, time, conditional-statements

This is my first question, as I have started to code recently.

here it goes...

I dont know how to do it, so I haven't coded it yet.
The idea is to have a Conditional to try doing something for x seconds, and if nothing happens on this x seconds, then do something to try it again.

Like this..

```
Try for 5 seconds to: 
  click on element to download something # <- this I know how to do
if nothing happens: # <- no error, just not executed the line above
  refresh the page
  try again:
finally:
  You have your file
```

sorry for my English, as it is not my primary language and I am also learning it...

Comment: Please include some amount of a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Since we don't know what packages you are using, there exists a large number of possible solutions.

Answer (score 1):

what web scraping tool you are using? selenium ? I can only give you my
logic if you do not post your code.

```
import datetime

def page_refresh():
    print('refresh page')
    driver.refresh()

def check_and_wait():
    status_ready = False
    while (not status_ready):
        start_time = datetime.now()
        while(not status_ready and datetime.now()-start_time<5): # loop 5 seconds
            if(condtion == True):  # if something happen
                status_ready = True
                return  
        page_refresh()   # nothing happen , loop again
```